# Unable to import 'rxjs' into angular 5 application

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am trying to import

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

however, I keep getting the error
"Property 'Map' does not exist on type 'Observable"

I have tried different imports, and different combinations of imports for rxjs. Each one produces the same or a Black-listed error. I have allowed rxjs in tslint.json, but still get the error stated above.

with

```
Import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

It gives me: "Module has no exported member 'Observable'"

this is what I am working with:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response, RequestOptions, Headers} from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  baseUrl = 'http://localhost:5000/api/auth';
  userToken: any;

constructor(private http: Http) { }

login(model: any) {
  const headers = new Headers({'Content-type': 'application/json'});
  const options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
  return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'login', model, options).map((response: Response) => {
    const user = response.json();
    if (user) {
      localStorage.setItem('token', user.tokenString);
      this.userToken = user.tokenString;
    }
  });
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your imports should be something like the following in RxJS6:

(1) rxjs: Creation methods, types, schedulers and utilities

```
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
```

(2) rxjs/operators: All pipeable operators:

```
import { map, filter, scan } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

For more information read the [migration guide](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md) and [import paths](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md#import-paths).

Also use [pipe](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md#operator-pipe-syntax) instead of chaining, for example:

```
 login(model: any) {
  const headers = new Headers({'Content-type': 'application/json'});
  const options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
  return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'login', model, options).pipe(

    map((response: Response) => {
    const user = response.json();
    if (user) {
      localStorage.setItem('token', user.tokenString);
      this.userToken = user.tokenString;
    }
  }));

}
```

Comment: @siva636 I just tried what you recommended, I am still getting "Property 'Map' does not exist on type 'Observable'"

Comment: You need to use pipe instead of chaining

Comment: Yes, this is for RxJS6, you seem to be using RxJS6 based on the error message you get.